# Return specific type within Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, typeclass, type-systems

I have a pretty general question about Haskell's type system. I'm trying to become familiar with it, and I have the following function:

```
getN :: Num a => a
getN = 5.0 :: Double
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Double'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `getN' at Perlin.hs:15:12
In the expression: 5.0 :: Double
In the definition of `getN': getN = 5.0 :: Double
```

As I understand this, the function is set up to "return" a type in the class Num. Double is in this class (http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Num_c.html), so I would have expected that it would be okay to "return" a Double in this case.

Can someone explain this please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A function with signature `Num a => a` is expected to work for *any* type in the class `Num`. The implementation `5.0 :: Double` just works for *one* type, not for *all* types of the class, so the compiler complains.

An example of a generic function would be:

```
square :: (Num a) => a -> a
square x = x * x
```

This works for *any* type that is a `Num`. It works for doubles, integers and whatever other numbers you want to use. Because of that it can have a generic type signature that just requires the parameter to be in class `Num`. (Type class `Num` is necessary because the function uses multiplication with `*`, which is defined there)

Comment: +1 - We can write the above function type as `forall a . Num a => a` -> It has to work *for any* type.

Answer (score 9):

To add to sth's answer: Haskell is not object-oriented. It's not true that `Double` is a subclass of `Num`, so you cannot return a `Double` if you promise to return a polymorphic `Num` value, like you can in, say, Java.

When you write `getN :: Num a => a` you promise to return a value that is fully polymorphic within the `Num` constraint. Effectively this means that you can only use functions from the `Num` type class, such as `+`, `*`, `-` and `fromInteger`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out *Existentially quantified types*.

One way to solve it would be to define a new data type

```
data NumBox = forall n. Num n => NumBox n
```

You'll need `-XExistentialQuantification` to get this to work.

Now you can write something like

```
getN :: NumBox
getN = NumBox (5.0 :: Double)
```

You can also define a `NumBox`-list as

```
let n3 = [NumBox (4.0 :: Double), NumBox (1 :: Integer), NumBox (1 :: Int) ]
```