# Haskell rigid type?

Tags: haskell, types, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return specific type within Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534224/return-specific-type-within-haskell)

This code:

```
class Alpha a where
    half :: Real f => a -> f

instance Alpha Double where
    half a = a/2.0
```

produces this error:

```
rigid.hs:6:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `f' against inferred type `Double'
      `f' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `half' at rigid.hs:3:17
    In the expression: a / 2.0
    In the definition of `half': half a = a / 2.0
    In the instance declaration for `Alpha Double'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why?

**EDIT**: Figuring out the business of rigid type, I think I've arrived at a more focused question. How do I convert a Double into a value that satisfies Ord and Num? That is, a function that gets me `(Ord a, Num a) => Double -> a`?

Comment: How about `(fromRational . toRational) :: (Fractional a,  Real b) => a -> b`?

Comment: ony: Your types are backwards; `(fromRational . toRational) :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b`. This is also known as `realToFrac`.

Answer (score 2):

You are claiming that `half` can convert the type `a` into any `Real` type. But your `half` can only convert `a` (`Double`) to `Double`.

Comment: How do I do the following: `(Ord a, Num a) => Double -> a`?

Answer (score 2):

> That is, a function that gets me (Ord a, Num a) => Double -> a?

The question is, what semantics do you want from it? Semantics is not always determined by the type, even in Haskell.

An example of such function (even without `Ord a` constraint) is:

```
doubleToNum = fromInteger . round
```

It satisfies the type you want, but e.g. it will not give you identity if you apply it to get `Double`.

Comment: I suppose I want the identity. Maybe I'm thinking about the types all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find very many interesting functions that can
convert a `Double` into *any* instance of `Ord` and `Num`. You can
create some pretty wild types that satisfy those two constraints.

Without knowing anything else, the only way you can construct values
out of thin air is using `fromInteger`. And the `Ord` instance isn't
going to help you, as far as I can see.

So you could do something like:

```
f :: (Ord a, Num a) => Double -> a
f = fromInteger . floor
```

Or even more trivially, `f = const 0`. :) But there's not much you
can do with the fractional part of your `Double`s, because there
is no guarantee that your target type has anything fractional about
it.

Perhaps you are looking for `Fractional a => Double -> a`?
Then you could use `realToFrac`.

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is truncate (or round) when the target type is not fractional, but keep the fractional part if the target type supports that. If so, then you'll need to make the target type part of what varies in your class, using an extension like "multi-parameter type classes" or "associated types". Or just treat those two cases separately, each with its own class.

Answer (score 1):

STOP!

Take a deep breath, and write out what it is that you "really" want.

I am going to stop trying to guess something that you'll like, and ask for another rephrasal. I think `realToFrac` may do what you're looking for, but I'm not sure.

Are you looking for a function that takes a Double and, somehow "invents" a new type that is a member of Ord and Num, but with no more specified behavior? Do you want a way to use a Double with some other type that you already have in mind?

Just as a small "thought experiment", imagine the computer tries to use your function on a Bool - could you phrase the question in such a way that it makes sense somehow on a Bool, or it clearly could not work with a Bool?

I'm sorry I couldn't answer your question as asked, but hoping that I've helped you to somehow get a better answer.