# Haskell - couldn't match expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell, compilation

On this code there's no way to do it polymorphic:

```
data NumericExpr e = Var e | Const e | Times [e] | Div e e deriving (Show,Read)

readCommand:: a -> b
readCommand entrada = Var 3
```

It gives me a big error which I can't copy:

> couldn't match expected type b with actual type NumericExpr e0 b is a
>   rigid type variable bound by the type signature for readcommand :: a
>   -> b

---

EDIT:

not working yet with:

```
data NumericExpr e = Var e | Const e | Plus [e] | Minus [e] | Times [e] | Div e e deriving (Show,Read)
data Expr e = Num e | String e

readCommand:: Expr b => a -> b
readCommand entrada = Var 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return specific type within Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534224/return-specific-type-within-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying that `readCommand` can produce results of any type `b` that the user requests, but you produce the result `Var 3`, which is a `NumericExpr e` (for some numeric type `e`). So in fact you can only produce results of type `NumericExpr e`, not any type. So your type signature is incorrect. It needs to be `readCommand :: Num b => a -> NumericExpr b` or just `readCommand :: a -> NumericExpr Integer` if you want to decide on a specific type for `3`.

Note that there is no possible function of type `a -> b` (without any constraints on `b`) that ever produces a result. That is any possible function of that type would loop forever or crash.

Comment: The problem is the return wont be always a numericExpr but it could also be booleanExpr (which is string)

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez Then you need a type `data Expr = Num NumericExpr | Bool BolleanExpr`. Or better yet, don't have separate numeric and boolean expression types in the first place.

Comment: Why shouldnt i separate them? Though your last comment helped me, i will try it

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez Because usually it leads to more problems than it solves. For example: your `NumericExpr` type has a case `Var` for variables. Presumably `BooleanExpr` would also need a case for variables, right? So let's call that `BoolVar`. Now your parser sees a variable name. Should it produce a `Var` or a `BoolVar`? You can't really know at this point unless you carry around type information for variables through the parser. That isn't usually information you need or want to keep track of in the parser and it makes your code much more painful than it needs to be.

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez `Expr` isn't a type class, it needs to be `readCommand :: Num b => a -> Expr b`. If that's confusing, you should read up on types and type classes. You also need `Num (Var 3)` instead of just `Var 3`, so that the result has the right type. And you need to change the definition of `Expr`, so that `Num` and `Bool` take a `NumericExpr e` and `BooleanExpr e` respectively, instead of just an `e`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107783/discussion-between-daniel-roca-lopez-and-sepp2k).